# Error on Infinite scroll with Ajax, PHP and MySQL

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, infinite-scroll

I am trying to implement an infinite scroll in my application but at the moment of reaching the end of my page, this throws the error that places.

This is the `ajax` code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(window).scroll(function() {
        if($(window).scrollTop() + $(window).height() >= $(document).height()) {
            var last_id = $(".post-id:last").attr("id");
            loadMoreData(last_id);
        }
    });

    function loadMoreData(last_id){
      $.ajax(
            {
                url: '/loadMoreData.php?last_id=' + last_id,
                type: "get",
                beforeSend: function()
                {
                    $('.ajax-load').show();
                }
            })
            .done(function(data)
            {
                $('.ajax-load').hide();
                $("#post-data").append(data);
            })
            .fail(function(jqXHR, ajaxOptions, thrownError)
            {
                  alert('server not responding...');
            });
    }
</script>
```

Here, is where I show the data from th `DataBase`:

```
<?php while ($post = $result -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){ ?>

    <div class="box-list" id="post-data">
        <div class="item">
            <div class="row">
              <p class="post-id hidde" id="<?php echo $post['id']; ?>">
                <div class="col-md-1 hidden-sm hidden-xs">
                    <div class="img-item"><img src="<?php echo OTRA; ?>/images/<?php echo $post['thumb']; ?>" alt=""></div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-11">
                    <h3 class="no-margin-top"><a href="single.php?id=<?php echo $post['id']; ?>"><?php echo $post['titulo']; ?> <i class="fa fa-link color-white-mute font-1x"></i></a></h3>
                    <h5><span class="color-black"><?php echo $post['company']; ?></span> - <span class="color-white-mute"><?php echo $post['locacion']; ?></span></h5>
                    <p class="text-truncate "><?php echo $post['extracto']; ?></p>
                    <div>
                    <span class="color-white-mute"><?php echo fecha($post['fecha']); ?></span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
<?php } ?>
```

and this id the other `PHP` file to load more data:

```
<?php session_start();

require 'extras/config.php';
require 'functions.php';

comprobarSession();

$conexion = conexion($bd_config);

$qry = "SELECT * FROM publications WHERE id > '$_GET['last_id']' ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT 8";
$result = $conexion->query($qry);
print_r ($result);

$json = include('views/empleos.php');

echo json_encode($json);
```

on the `Developer Tool` of `Chrome` the error that show me is

> jquery.js:8706 GET http://localhost/loadMoreData.php?last_id=9 404 (Not Found)

Comment: well thats a 404... that means your load-more-endpoint is not found under http://localhost/loadMoreData.php. By what url can you call that script with your browser (without js involved)?

Comment: @simon.ro you have reason, in my `script` i have `/loadMoreData` is without the `/` and I remove tha but there's another problem `Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '' (T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE), expecting identifier (T_STRING) or variable (T_VARIABLE) or number (T_NUM_STRING) in C:\xampp\htdocs\talvez usuario\loadMoreData.php on line 10`

Comment: First, be warned that "infinite scroll" bloats the RAM usage of some user browsers.  I consider it evil and avoid such pages.  (Browser developers seem to wrongly assume that that all users have infinite RAM today.)

Comment: Congratulations -- You did the "continue where you left off" code instead of `LIMIT` and `OFFSET`.  It is amazing how few people have discovered that.

Answer (score 0):

What is the name of that php file?  Sounds like it  is not `loadMoreData.php`?  Perhaps it is `loadData.php`, and the AJAX call should be changed?

Comment: actually it is, just that like I says before, it wasn't `/loadMoreData.php` it was `loadMoreData` without `/` but, if I remove the slash it make a Infinite cycle, but never change of id